# How can i change a URL path in php

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url

Is it possible to change a URL with php

Example:

original URL: http://example.com/path123

Change to: http://example.com/page.php?url=path123

I need this when someone visits the original URL.

Comment: are you looking for a specific redirect for path123 or a catch all redirect so they could enter anything? the answer will be in .htaccess rewriting rather than a php redirect itself most likely

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in /path123.php or index.php if you're rewriting requests (eg: using apache mod_rewrite).

```php
<?php

$url = str_replace('?', '&', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header('Location: http://example.com/page.php?url='.$url);

?>
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to redirect to the new url.. is there a reason for that? Thanks i appreciate your answer :)

Comment: @Flylink does it crashing? or just showing blank screen? I have not tested the code. but I think it should work if configured correctly

Comment: @Flylink please search about apache mod_rewrite and redirect rules. Doing that with apache config is easier than php (actually you'll need to configure apache too if you need to do with php)